# Why would a single ghost record remain in a few random indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I used the `ghost_record_count` column to find indexes/partitions that have ghost records. I found a few that have one such record. I then tried to queue them up for processing by scanning all pages:

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM T WITH (READUNCOMMITTED, INDEX(idx))
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

I then waited at least 10 seconds to let the ghost cleanup task run. But the ghost records do not disappear. I also tried restarting the server. No ghost related trace flags are in use.

This is not an actual problem that I'm having. I'm trying to understand ghost cleanup in general. Why do the counters not drop to zero in tables that have no writes?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when all rows from the *first page* of the index structure are deleted.

Ghost cleanup doesn't deallocate the page as it normally* would to avoid having to update extra metadata that refers to the first page of the index. It's just not work it is set up to perform.

Instead, it leaves the page empty with a single ghosted record. The ghost is visible on the page but not accounted for in the places ghost cleanup looks for work.

The page can be deallocated with `ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE`.

---

<sub>* Before SQL Server 2005, ghost cleanup never deallocated empty pages.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in this article [Inside the Storage Engine: Ghost cleanup in depth](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-ghost-cleanup-in-depth/)

> When a record is deleted, apart from it being marked as a ghost
> record, the page that the record is on is also marked as having ghost
> records in one of the allocation maps – the PFS page (post coming
> soon!) – and in its page header. Marking a page as having ghost
> records in a PFS page also changes the database state to indicate that
> there are some ghost records to cleanup – somewhere. **Nothing tells the
> ghost cleanup task to clean the specific page that the delete happened
> on – yet. That only happens when the next scan operation reads the
> page and notices that the page has ghost records.**

So it's not cleaned up until the page is read again

Comment: That's why the OP is using a `COUNT_BIG` with index hint. To force all pages in the index to be scanned.

Comment: Also from that article "The ghost cleanup task will leave a single record on the page to avoid having to deallocate empty data or index pages.".